# Accessing UiPath Credential Store created by previous developer

Tags: credentials, uipath

I am extremely new to UiPath.  I have inherited a project from an experienced UiPath developer.  I am trying to find the username and password he uses to login to a specific app.  Because the project is not working when executing in the development environment, it is possible the password has expired. I am on the machine he used to develop the project, but logged in under my name.  I have found the process that does the "Get Credential". I am using a message box to show the username at this point.  When I run the process The "Get Credential" activity returns the error "you are not authenticated Error Code:0"  I have researched the error and found several answers as to why it is happening, but not what to do to either fix my problem or get around the problem.   The UiPath.systems.Activites version used is 21.4.1. I am aware of the concept of the CredentialStores, but can't seem to find the one used for this project.  Where would I find the name of the credential store used? How do I find the username? I need to test the change I made for a user request.

Comment: Hard to answer. First can you check if Orchestrator Assets or the Windows Credential Store. Then check your Config file's `Settings` sheet.

Comment: @kwoxer - I think that's part of my problem, I can't tell which is being used.  There is a Credential Store in Orchestrator called Orchestrator Database.  On the developer's machine  and the test application machine (that runs the unattended robot) there is a windows credential store referencing the UIPATH-ROBOT-AGENT/test web site.

Comment: For a quick check you should now go and do testings. First go in the Config.xlsx file and see if there is the name of the Cred Asset located in. If so delete it and try again. If still working the process is using the Windows Credential Store. So then go on there.

Comment: @kwoxer - I looked in the config.xlsx for the project on the developer's machine and did not see any reference to Credential Assets.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to close this question as I have determined the correct password for what I needed to do.  I have no need to get into the credential stores for a password.

Credential stores and password were not the actual issue with the error I was receiving.  The error "Loading asset PreAuth_Citrix_FolderName failed:
You are not authenticated! Error code: 0" by referencing the word authenticated, I assumed it had to do with passwords.  As I did more research I found the issue to be the new security certificate installed on our web server.  While orchestrator recognized the new cert, the Identity Server was not updated with the new thumbprint.  I found the information I need at this link https://forum.uipath.com/t/get-asset-you-are-not-authenticated-error-code-0/343910.  Once I updated the Identity Server  thumbprint, I no longer received the error and my jobs ran. (not successful, but at least they ran past this error!)